# C# XML - Deserializing a list of classes

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm working with an XML document which is generated using C# from a list of objects (of the 'People' class)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfDeviceInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="DeviceInfoCollection">
  <DeviceInfo>
    <Partition>0</Partition>
    <SerialID>3117132000001</SerialID>
    <AzureID>2d680cd1-7320-43a9-87d4-75a2698771a3</AzureID>
    <FirmwareVersion>3.0.0</FirmwareVersion>
  </DeviceInfo>
  <DeviceInfo>
    <Partition>0</Partition>
    <SerialID>3117132000002</SerialID>
    <AzureID>646ca461-9352-4746-9fa6-6308010059fb</AzureID>
    <FirmwareVersion>1.1.2</FirmwareVersion>
  </DeviceInfo>
```

**My goal is to deserialize this back into a** `List<DeviceInfo>` **variable.**

I've tried the following

```
            var xDoc = XDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath + "/devicesTEST.xml");
            if (File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + "/devicesTEST.xml").Length > 0)
            {

                var envs = from e in xDoc.Root.Descendants("DeviceInfo")
                           select new DeviceInfo
                           {
                               SerialID = (string)e.Element("SerialID"),
                           };
                Manager.Devices = envs.ToList();
            }
```

and it's working for me on another XML file.

**Update**

Contrary to previous belief, it turns out there is no error, the list just doesn't get populated with the values extracted from the XML.

Comment: I've put on my moderator hat and removed a bunch of comments that were going off-topic; I'll summarize as: [MCVE==good](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML namespaces; in your xml, the namespace is defined by `xmlns="DeviceInfoCollection"` - but your code assumes it is the empty (default) namespace. Since xml namespaces are inherited, you need to tell it the namespace throughout:

```
XNamespace ns = "DeviceInfoCollection";
var devices = from e in xDoc.Root.Descendants(ns + "DeviceInfo")
           select new DeviceInfo
           {
               SerialID = (string)e.Element(ns + "SerialID"),
           };

foreach(var device in devices)
{
    Console.WriteLine(device.SerialID);
}
```

Comment: I don't know how or why you managed to understand my question whilst others cried about it but it's clear to me that with enough knowledge, you don't need too much detail to diagnose a problem. This was indeed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Anaconda I think it is really a question of *how much* effort it places on the reader; the more readable and complete the question, the more people will be able to look at it and think "oh, I know what this is". If a question needs more deciphering, it a: limits the folks who can chew through that fog, and b: means that even then: people can't be *anywhere near* as sure in their answer.

Comment: that makes sense to me. I will try to adhere to the resource you attached in this post in future - and I appreciate the sincerity.